# Java Spring + Elasticsearch - Globalsearch: Resolving Logic From Person Type to Country Type

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have a "globalsearch" index that stores "person", "address", "country" information in one single index:

```
{
"id":"PER_0001",
"type":"person",
"addressId":"ADDR_001"
},
{
"id":"ADDR_001",
"type":"address",
"countryId":"COUNT_001"
},
{
"id":"COUNT_001",
"type":"country",
"name":"India"
}
```

Given type=PERSON and id="PER_001", how can I "map" or query so that I can retrieve the country COUNT_001 details?

Comment: have u tried anything ? can u add the code ?

Comment: This is not really a use case to use Elasticsearch for. You would better be using a relational database for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shold use [Multiple levels of parent join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/parent-join.html#_multiple_levels_of_parent_join). And use [has_child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) Query.

Here is my examples.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_join_field": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "country": "address",  
          "address": "person" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "id": "COUNT_001",
  "type": "country",
  "name": "India",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "country"
  }
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/2?routing=1&refresh
{
 "id":"ADDR_001",
"type":"address",
"countryId":"COUNT_001",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "address",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}


PUT my-index-000001/_doc/3?routing=1&refresh
{
"id":"PER_0001",
"type":"person",
"addressId":"ADDR_001",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "person",
    "parent": "2"
  }
}


GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "address",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": [
            "person"
          ],
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "type.keyword": {
                      "value": "person"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "id.keyword": {
                      "value": "PER_0001"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```